# htaccess redirect problem

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

So,

Say I have my shopping cart at **foo.com/a**

I want to redirect shoppers to **foo.com/b**

At **foo.com** my `.htaccess` contains

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(index\.html)?$ foo.com/b
```

But people still land on **foo.com/a** (if they type it/have it bookmarked) It doesn't redirect.  Only redirects if they land on **foo.com**

I'm sure it's a trivial problem.  Can anyone help?

Talk to you all later.

Comment: there is probably nothing matching the pattern. Try `^/index.html?(.*)$` - Please give better information as there is no foo.com/a in the pattern, its hard to guess the goal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

Redirect permanent foo.com/b

In the foo.com/a .htacccess file did the trick.

Comment: Although the directive as posted would seem to be invalid? You are missing the source URL and the target URL is malformed if `foo.com` is intended to be a hostname?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Redirect 301 / https://foo.com/b
```

Just place this in a `.htaccess` file in the directory that you want to redirect.

If you want to change the HTTP status code (redirect type) then just change the number.

Here is a link that talks more about it for reference.

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: You need to include `/a` in the source URL (ie. `Redirect 301 /a https://foo.com/b`), otherwise when you request `/a`, you'll be redirected to `/ba`, since the `Redirect` directives is prefix-matching and everything after the match (ie. everything after `/`) is copied onto the end of the target URL.